# Send an email in PHP - Blank email receive

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send an email with PHP.

My problem is actually, the email sent is blank...

My PHP function:

```
function sendMail($template, $Email_Subject, $USR_Id, $USR_Email) {

    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'subject' => $Email_Subject
        )
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    $message = file_get_contents('../../mail/'.$template.'.php', false, $context);

    // Start configuring the email
    $headers .= 'From: Company <noreply@company.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    mail($USR_Email, $Email_Subject, $message, $headers); 
}
```

My template.php page:

```
$message = 
'<html>
...
<h1>Subject is : '.$_POST['subject'].'</h1>
...
<\html>';
echo $message;
```

I call the function like this:

```
sendMail("template", "Account Activation", $USR_Id, $USR_Email);
```

What is strange is when I echo the `$message`, it do not echo me `Subject is : ...`. It echoes me `Subject is : '.$_POST['subject'].'`. Like if PHP dont't work...

Anyone to help me please ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you echo `$message` in template.php? It seems there's just a variable!!!

Comment: Yes. I tryed with return too.

Comment: Try it with `echo`... Return is not appropriate for this case...

Comment: I tryed with echo $message. The same... :(

Comment: Perhaps your file trails are incorrect. `../../` Can you provide your file structure? try using this tool to help you create it on text: **http://filestructuregenerator.com**

Comment: You cannot use a HTTP `$context` with local paths. And PHP won't run then either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to send an email, why are you using stream-contexts and $_POST? This should be done using output buffering (http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php):

```
function sendMail($template, $Email_Subject, $USR_Id, $USR_Email) {

    // everything output between ob_start and ob_end_clean will be stored
    // in a temporary buffer, instead of being send the browser
    ob_start();
    require('../../mail/'.$template.'.php');
    $message = ob_get_clean();

    // Start configuring the email
    $headers  = 'From: Company <noreply@email.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    mail($USR_Email, $Email_Subject, $message, $headers); 
}
```

In your template you can use all variables that are available in the sendMail function, so use $Email_Subject instead of $_POST. Obviously, if there is anything in $_POST you'd like to print you can still do that using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a class to send email. Please let me know if it is useful to you

```
    <?php
class scSendMail
{
    protected $from;
    protected $toList;
    protected $replyTo;
    protected $subject;
    protected $message;
    public function __construct()
    {   
        register_shutdown_function(array($this,'__destruct'));
        $this->setFrom("updates@planetonnet.com");
        $this->setReplyTo("noreply@planetonnet.com");
        $this->setSubject("Update from PlanetOnNet.com");
    }



    public function __destruct()
    {
        unset($this->from);
        unset($this->toList);
        unset($this->replyTo);
        unset($this->subject);
        unset($this->message);
    }


    public function sendMail()
    {
        $return =NULL;
        $headers ='From: '.$this->getFrom()."\r\n" .
                  'Reply-To: '.$this->getReplyTo(). "\r\n" .
                  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".
                  'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n".
                  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        foreach($this->toList as $to)
        {
            if(mail($to, $this->getSubject(), $this->getMessage(), $headers)) 
            {
                $return.='<br>mail sent to: '. $to;
            }
            else 
            {
                $return.='<br>mail couldnt sent to: '. $to;
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }

    public function setFrom ($tmpFrom )
    {
        $this->from = $tmpFrom ;
    }
    public function getFrom ()
    {
        return $this->from ;
    }

    public function addInToList ($tmpTo )
    {
        $this->toList[] = $tmpTo ;
    }

    public function setReplyTo ($tmpReplyTo )
    {
        $this->replyTo = $tmpReplyTo ;
    }
    public function getReplyTo ()
    {
        return $this->replyTo  ;
    }

    public function setSubject ($tmpSubject )
    {
        $this->subject= $tmpSubject ;
    }
    public function getSubject ()
    {
        return $this->subject ;
    }

    public function setMessage ($tmpMessage )
    {
        $tmpMessage.='<br>You are getting this message on behalf of 
                        <a href="http://planetonnet.com/">planetonnet.com</a><br>
                      login to your account area for more ';
        $this->message = stripslashes($tmpMessage) ;
    }
    public function getMessage ()
    {
        return  $this->message ;
    }


}
?>
```

And while using it, just use as follow

```
<?php
include_once("scSendMail.php");
$test1=new scSendMail();
$test1->addInToList("abc@example.com");
$test1->addInToList("abc@anotherexample.com");
$test1->setSubject("Hi! This is test email");
echo $test1->sendMail();
?>
```