# Send an email templating during a include in PHP

Tags: php

I try to send a email with templates. I have severals templates (one to reset password, one to upgrade the account, ...).

All of these templates are stored in a `mail` directory and it looks like this:

```
<?php
    // Template to reset password
    $message = "Hello Mr, ...";
    $subject = "Your new password";
    $email = "mr@company.com";
?>
```

Now I have a function:

```
function sendMail($template, $USR_Id) {

    ob_start();
    include 'mail/'.$template.'.php';
    $message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // Start configuring the email
    $headers .= 'From: company <noreply@company.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers); 
}
```

My problem:

How to get back the infos store in my template files (i.e.: `$subject` and `$email`) ?

Comment: Just include the template. That output buffering is not needed.

Comment: What do you mean: "get back"? Return these variables from function in an array.

Comment: I want to use these variables included in my template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use php variables from an included php file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483759/how-to-use-php-variables-from-an-included-php-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good to see you using [my previously suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095436/send-an-email-in-php-blank-email-receive/31098913#31098913) setup. That setup depended on the `echo` however, and if you're not using that you can make your function even simpler. If your templates look like that; you can simply do:

```
function sendMail($template, $USR_Id) {

    include 'mail/'.$template.'.php';

    // Start configuring the email
    $headers .= 'From: company <noreply@company.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers); 
}
```

If you use [include / require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php); you can use all variables across multiple files